# An Inequality about power numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Which number is larger? $4^{25}$ or $9^{15}$. Why? I know that it used powers of 2 and 3 but how?

Comment: We can do this in our heads.  Simplify to a power of 2 vs. a power of 3, then take out (taking a root) the greatest common divisor of the exponents.  When you have done that, you'll have only a couple of two digit numbers to compare.

Answer (score 14):

$4^{25} = 2^{50} = 32^{10} > 27^{10} = 3^{30} = 9^{15}$
So first one larger.

Comment: Very good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

We want to compare $4^{25}$ and $9^{15}$. Rewrite as $2^{50}$ and $3^{30}$. Now, we have that
$$
\frac{2^{50}}{3^{30}}>1\iff \frac{2^5}{3^3}>1 \iff \frac{32}{27}>1
$$
and since the latter is true, we have $2^{50}>3^{30}$.
Note that the first equivalency holds because $\sqrt[10]{\cdot}$ is a monotone function.

Answer (score 3):

It's not hard to see that
$$4^5=1024>9^3=729$$
and now raise to the power $5$.

Comment: Actually $4^5 = 1024$ and $9^3 = 729$ (though of course this doesn't affect the conclusion).

Comment: LoL it's an incomprehensible error I do not know how I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$log(4^{25})=50log2=50(.3)=15 \\$(approximately) 
$$ \\ $$
$log(9^{15})=30log3=14.31 $(approximately)

So, 1st one is bigger.

$$ \\ $$

Alternatively, $(4^{25})=(4^5)^5$ and 
$(9^{15})=(9^3)^5$
$$ \\ $$
$4^5>9^3$

Comment: Please without using $\log$.

Comment: You've made a mistake in the 2nd approximation anyway.

Comment: Also, I think you meant $\log{9^{15}} = 30 \log{3}$ not $45 \log{3}$